# Passing props from child to parent Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have this child component called **BaseCardAnnotationOption**

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="text-h5 text-center indigo darken-1 lighten-2">
      <slot name="title"> </slot>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="includeAnnotations1"
        label="Include Annotations"
        @change="deselectDisabled()"
      ></v-checkbox>

      <v-radio-group class="mt-0 ml-12" v-model="annotationOption1">
        <v-radio
          :value="embedIntoImage"
          label="Embedded Into Image"
          :disabled="includeAnnotations1 === false"
        ></v-radio>
        <v-radio
          :value="burnIntoImage"
          label="Burn Into Image"
          :disabled="includeAnnotations1 === false"
        ></v-radio>

        <v-checkbox
          class="mt-0 ml-8"
          v-model="maintainColor1"
          label="Maintain Annotation Color "
          :disabled="annotationOption1 === 0 || includeAnnotations1 === false"
        ></v-checkbox>
      </v-radio-group>

      <v-checkbox
        class="mt-0"
        v-model="burnReduction1"
        label="Burn Reduction"
      ></v-checkbox>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseCardAnnotationOption",
  data() {
    return {
      includeAnnotations1: false,
      embedIntoImage: null,
      burnIntoImage: null,
      burnReduction1: false,
      maintainColor1: false,
      annotationOption1: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deselectDisabled() {
      return this.includeAnnotations1 === false
        ? ((this.annotationOption1 = null), (this.maintainColor1 = false))
        : ((this.annotationOption1 = 0), (this.maintainColor1 = false));
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

And i am using it in another parent component named **viewer** like this

```html
<base-card-annotation-option>
          <template v-slot:title>
            Print Document
          </template>
        </base-card-annotation-option>
```

Now i want to use this function in Viewer(parent) which requires data that has been
declared in BaseCardAnnotationOption(child) as shown below

```
     <base-tooltip-button
              @click="
                onPrintFile(
                  document,
                  asPdf,
                  includeAnnotations1,
                  annotationOption1,
                  burnReduction1,
                  maintainColor1
                )
              "
            >
              Print
              <template v-slot:toolTip>
                Print
              </template>
            </base-tooltip-button>
```

So basically some data has been declared in child which i want to send to parent . How can that be achieved ? Thanks

Comment: Your question is really strange. "In Viewer i want to recieve data as props which i am sending from BaseCardAnnotationOption" ....yet you say that `BaseCardAnnotationOption` is a child component of `viewer`. Props are for sending data from parent (`viewer`) to child (`BaseCardAnnotationOption`) not vice-versa. Please edit your question to make that clear

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear, i have updated my question

Comment: Maybe use scoped slots. The `viewer` get access to data from `options` using scope slots, which are then passed to the `button` component.